# obtener información de tabla usando dblink en SQL Server

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

Se puede obtener la informacion de una tabla SQL a travez de un link server? ya que hago mi consulta pero no me devuelve informacion de mi tabla o quiza tengo mal mi query, no marca error solo no muestra nada de informacion, uso esta query

```html
       SELECT TABLE_NAME TABLE2, 
       COLUMN_NAME COLUMN2,
    CASE WHEN DATA_TYPE='VARCHAR' THEN 'VARCHAR('+Convert(VARCHAR(10),CHARacter_maximum_length)+')'
         WHEN DATA_TYPE='NVARCHAR' THEN 'NVARCHAR('+Convert(VARCHAR(10),CHARacter_maximum_length)+')'
       WHEN DATA_TYPE='VARBINARY' THEN 'VARBINARY('+Convert(VARCHAR(10),CHARacter_maximum_length)+')'
       WHEN DATA_TYPE='CHAR' THEN 'CHAR('+Convert(VARCHAR(10),CHARacter_maximum_length)+')'
       WHEN DATA_TYPE='DECIMAL' THEN 'DECIMAL('+Convert(VARCHAR(10),NUMERIC_Precision_Radix)+','+Convert(VARCHAR(10),NUMERIC_Scale)+')'
       WHEN DATA_TYPE='NUMERIC' THEN 'DECIMAL('+Convert(VARCHAR(10),NUMERIC_Precision_Radix)+','+Convert(VARCHAR(10),NUMERIC_Scale)+')'
        ELSE DATA_TYPE
    END DATA_TYPE2,
    CASE WHEN IS_NULLABLE='NO' THEN 'NOT NULL'
         ELSE 'NULL' 
    END IS_NULLABLE2
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
 WHERE Table_Name='[17X.X.X.X].Apoyo.dbo.TEST51'
```

Comment: Eh, disculpa... ahí no tiene nada que ver el linked server. Estás buscando en el catálogo local información de una tabla remota??? Ya te tenía una respuesta pero esa NO es tu pregunta real... un linked server no trae TODA la BD remota, sólo te permite conectarte con una cuenta _de allá_ desde un usuario _acá_. Pero esa búsqueda que tienes no tiene mucho sentido porque tu BD _acá_ no tiene ni idea de qué tablas hay _allá_.

Comment: @Alfabravo lo que queria hacer era saber era el nombre de las columnas que  tiene la tabla la BD de allá, cambie la query que presente en un inicio pero no muestra nada

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo por qué usas la IP del servidor remoto. De acuerdo a la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15), lo que usas es **el nombre** del linked server que definiste al crearlo en tu BD local.

Ejemplo: el linked server se llama BDREMOTA, debes usar BDREMOTA.*BD*.*esquema*.*tabla*. Si usas el esquema por defecto de la BD (digamos, dbo), entonces es `BDREMOTA.BD.tabla`

Ahora, para averiguar sobre la metadata en el servidor remoto... hay que preguntarle a la BD remota. Un linked server es una herramienta preparada para que unos usuarios de la BD local *puedan* **conectarse a la BD remota con un usuario de la BD remota**. Tu BD no tiene de repente una copia completa de la BD remota. Esa BD INFORMATION_SCHEMA tiene metadata... de las tablas que hay localmente. No tiene por qué saber qué pasa por allá lejos en el servidor enlazado.

Sin saber cómo habrás creado o configurado el linked server, la consulta sería *máaaaas o menos* así (teniendo en cuenta qué ofrece INFORMATION_SCHEMA en cualquier base de datos SQLServer, siguiendo [la documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/system-information-schema-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)):

```
SELECT 
    TABLE_NAME TABLE2, 
    COLUMN_NAME COLUMN2,
    CASE WHEN DATA_TYPE='VARCHAR' THEN 'VARCHAR('+Convert(VARCHAR(10),CHARacter_maximum_length)+')'
         WHEN DATA_TYPE='NVARCHAR' THEN 'NVARCHAR('+Convert(VARCHAR(10),CHARacter_maximum_length)+')'
       WHEN DATA_TYPE='VARBINARY' THEN 'VARBINARY('+Convert(VARCHAR(10),CHARacter_maximum_length)+')'
       WHEN DATA_TYPE='CHAR' THEN 'CHAR('+Convert(VARCHAR(10),CHARacter_maximum_length)+')'
       WHEN DATA_TYPE='DECIMAL' THEN 'DECIMAL('+Convert(VARCHAR(10),NUMERIC_Precision_Radix)+','+Convert(VARCHAR(10),NUMERIC_Scale)+')'
       WHEN DATA_TYPE='NUMERIC' THEN 'DECIMAL('+Convert(VARCHAR(10),NUMERIC_Precision_Radix)+','+Convert(VARCHAR(10),NUMERIC_Scale)+')'
        ELSE DATA_TYPE
    END DATA_TYPE2,
    CASE WHEN IS_NULLABLE='NO' THEN 'NOT NULL'
         ELSE 'NULL' 
    END IS_NULLABLE2
FROM 
    [MILINKEDSERVER].Apoyo.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
WHERE 
    Table_Name='TEST51'
```

(Si el *usuario remoto* no tiene permisos suficientes en la BD remota, no va a funcionar, tal como pasa si miras ese esquema information_schema en la BD local).

Comment: me genero error en el link server que el maximo de sufijos es 3, por otro lado lo que intente hacer era identificar que columnas hay en mi tabla del servidor B ya que muchas tablas del serividor A estan incompletas pero tengo que primero identificar

Comment: @Ivxn Respuesta editada. Puedes probar sin el where para que veas que sí te muestra info y luego buscas por el nombre de la tabla.